# How convert video to mp4 before upload to Google Storage?

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Currently, I have an API which uploads files to Google Storage. If user uploads video it should be converted to mp4. I took a look at [FFMEPG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and [Java wrapper around the FFmpeg](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper) , but I need to convert video directly from InputStream without writing into a disk. Is there any solution to convert InputStream into mp4?

Comment: Yes, you can pipe input to FFmpeg.

Comment: @szatmary how? I searched on the internet and didn't find how to pass InputStream, not file. Only one solution I found is to write cloud functions on google cloud compute engine and transcode video after uploading

Comment: You can transcode on the fly by piping to ffmpegs stdin.

Comment: @szatmary is there any java wrapper to use for this case?

Comment: I don't know, personally I would just use Java.lang.System